# Flutter Animated Widget not animting in GridView.count

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, gridview

I have a `GridView.count` and I want items inside of it to be animted depending on a certain state. Here is an example:

```
return Column(
  key: const Key('error'),
  children: [
    GridView.count(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      primary: true,
      key: UniqueKey(),
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      childAspectRatio: 0.8,
      crossAxisSpacing: context.paddings.newMedium,
      children: [
        AnimatedOpacity(
          key: const Key('green'),
          opacity: myCondition ? 0 : 1,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
        AnimatedOpacity(
          key: const Key('red'),
          opacity: myCondition ? 0 : 1,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          child: Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

But the code above is not working as expected. There is **no animation**.
What am I missing here? I tried adding `Key`s but that didn't help me.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: can you include the full widget

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh that is more or less the full widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is using `key: UniqueKey()`. It provides new instance on every frame is build. You can create a state instance or you can different key like ValueKey.

```dart
Column(
    key: const Key('error'),
    children: [
      GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        primary: true,
        key: ValueKey("GridViewAnimatedOpacity"),
```

Full snipppet

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool myCondition = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            myCondition = !myCondition;
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: Column(
        key: const Key('error'),
        children: [
          GridView.count(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            primary: true,
            key: ValueKey("GridViewAnimatedOpacity"),
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: 0.8,
            crossAxisSpacing: 2,
            children: [
              AnimatedOpacity(
                key: const Key('green'),
                opacity: myCondition ? 0 : 1,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                child: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedOpacity(
                key: const Key('red'),
                opacity: myCondition ? 0 : 1,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                child: Container(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you test that? It is not working for me. Same result

Comment: Yes & that's why I've asked for full minimal snippet

Comment: It does work for me.

Comment: you're right. Your answer is working. Thanks :)